# Multiple filebeat to one logstash. How to optimize the configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, filebeat

I have 10 servers that i have Filebeat installed in.
Each server monitors 2 applications, a total of 20 applications.

I have one Logstash server which collects all the above logs and passes it to Elasticsearch after filtering of these logs.

To read **one file from one server**, I use the below Logstash configuration:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter {
    grok {
match => {"message" =>"\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:Severity}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:Plugin}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:Servername}\](?<short_message>(.|\r|\n)*)"}
    }
} 
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["<ESserverip>:9200"]
    index => "groklogs"
}
          stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

And this is the filebeat configuration:

```
paths:
    - D:\ELK 7.1.0\elasticsearch-7.1.0-windows-x86_64\elasticsearch-7.1.0\logs\*.log

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["<logstaship>:5044"]
```

Can anyone please give me an example of

1. How i should convert the above to receive from multiple applications
   from multiple servers.
2. Should i configure multiple ports? How?
3. How should i use multiple Groks?
4. How can i optimize it in a single or minimal logstash configuration files?

How will a typical set up look. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **tags** in order to differentiate between applications (logs patterns).

As Filebeat provides metadata, the field **beat.name** will give you the ability to filter the server(s) you want.

Multiple inputs of type log and for each one a different tag should be sufficient.
See these examples in order to help you.

*Logstash*

```
filter {
    if "APP1" in [tags] {
        grok {
             ...
        }
    }
    if "APP2" in [tags] {
        grok {
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

*Filebeat*

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log 
  paths:
    - /var/log/system.log
    - /var/log/wifi.log
  tags: ["APP1"]
- type: log 
  paths:
    - "/var/log/apache2/*"
  tags: ["APP2"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation @dooms, I will try the same!